# How to filter Android database by column

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm writing an Android application for RC Cars. It uses a SQLite database, and saves the model of the car, car name and other variables.

Here's my code:

```
public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {
  return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
    KEY_CARNAME, KEY_TRACKNAME, KEY_TRACKSIZE, KEY_TRACKTRACTION, KEY_TRACKSURFACE, KEY_BODYTYPE,
    KEY_COMMENTS}, KEY_CARNAME + "=" + "'MTX-4'", null, null, null, null);
}
```

How can I display only the records that have a certain model of car named in the carname column? So far I can only filter the results by using `'MTX-4'` or some other literal string. I need to be able to replace that with a string variable like `String carName` or something, so I can filter by a user-defined carname.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace the 'MTX-4' with "?" as a parameter variable. Then replace the selectionArgs parameter (null in your example) with your list of parameters, e.g. new String[]{"MTX-4"} or new String[]{carName}

The following snippet is equivalent to yours.

```
return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
    KEY_CARNAME, KEY_TRACKNAME, KEY_TRACKSIZE, KEY_TRACKTRACTION, KEY_TRACKSURFACE, KEY_BODYTYPE, KEY_COMMENTS}, KEY_CARNAME + "=" + "?", new String[]{"MTX-4"}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Argh, beaten to it :p  +1, this is exactly what I was going to write. Actually, I'd add just one more comment. To make it a user defined string for the search, just add the "String carName" as an argument for your database query, and then replace Jim's `new String[]{"MTX-4"}` with `new String[]{carName}`. If you're already passing an array of strings, you don't need to bother with the `new String[]` part.

Comment: Jim and Steve, many many thanks for your prompt replies. That did the trick nicely! And in the process, you helped along my understanding of selection & selectionArgs. Thanks again! If you're ever in Wilts, UK, I'll buy you a beer! :)